# What is the latest version of IE supported on Windows Server 2008 SP2 (Non R2)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

What is the latest version of IE supported on Windows Server 2008  SP2 (Non-R2) and does Windows Server 2008 SP2 support Microsoft EDGE?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-server-eos-faq/end-of-support-windows-server-2008-2008r2), we can know that Windows Server 2008 approached end of support. IE browser's support is along with OS support. If the OS is end of support, IE is also end of support on the OS.

For the server versions Edge supports, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-supported-operating-systems#windows-server). It seems that Edge supports Windows Server 2008 R2 not Windows Server 2008 SP2.